# React not updating state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, state

I´m new to react. I´m trying to fetch an endpoints array. and I want to update the api's status every 15 seconds. I´m trying to do this

```
export const endpoints: string[] = [
  "accounts/health/status",
  "assets/health/status",
  "customers/health/status",
  "datapoints/health/status",
  "devices/health/status",
  "documents/health/status",
  "forms/health/status",
  "invites/health/status",
  "media/health/status",
  "messages/health/status",
  "namespaces/health/status",
  "orders/health/status",
  "patients/health/status",
  "relationships/health/status",
  "rules/health/status",
  "templates/health/status",
  "users/health/status",
  "workflows/health/status",
];
```

and I have this proxy in my package.json

```
  "proxy": "https://api.factoryfour.com/",
```

Here the rest of my code

```
const [data, setData] = useState<Response[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string[] | null[]>([]);

const effectRan = useRef(false);

  const fetching = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    endpoints.map(async (endpoint) => {
      return await axios
        .get(endpoint)
        .then((res) => {
          setData((prev) => [...prev, res.data]);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setError([...error, err.message]);
        });
    });
    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!effectRan.current) {
      fetching();
    }
    return () => {
      effectRan.current = true;
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      setData([]);
      setLoading(true);
      setError([]);

      await fetching();
    }, 15000);
  }, []);
```

but when the seTimeout runs every card duplicates and the state gets more data than before. even though I´m reseting the state to `setData([])` I just want to update the api's status. What can i do?

````
if (loading) return <Spinner />;
  return (
    <div className="card-container">
      {data.length ? (
        data.map((item) => {
          return (
            <Card
              key={generateKey()}
              hostname={item.hostname}
              message={item.message}
              success={item.success}
              time={item.time}
            />
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <Spinner />
      )}
      {error.length
        ? error.map((err) => (
            <ErrorCard key={generateKey()} message={err as string} />
          ))
        : null}
    </div>
    ```
````

Comment: Is it possible one or more of your endpoints always or sometimes take more than 15 seconds to return from the server?

Comment: Your `effectRan` is a little strange and could be causing issues. You have no dependency array which means it will run every render. You set `effectRan.current = true` as your cleanup function, but I'm not sure exactly how that plays with React 18 double firing effects on local. Why isn't that useEffect just firing once on mount? `useEffect(..., [])` Definitely make sure fetching() is called the expected amount of times. There's a lot going on here.. so I'd post your JSX as well.

Comment: Yeah. now I´m trying with the way someone told me below. I've updated code in the question as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a few things wrong here and one or more probably fixes it:

- You keep a ref around to track the first fetch but theres no need as you can do that by virtue of using `[]` in an effects deps array, which you already have.
- The loading state does not wait until all requests in flight finished.
- The 15 second interval does not wait until all requests launched are finished.
- You dont clear down the timer if the component unmounts and remounts.
- The data is not keyed against the endpoint which could land you in trouble if using React strictmode that runs affects twice in dev mode.

Your code, by design it seems, does append data each time one of the requests comes back -- but I think that was intentional?

```
  const [data, setData] = useState<Record<string, Response>>({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<Record<string, string | null>>({});

  const fetching = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    await Promise.all(
      endpoints.map((endpoint) => {
        return axios
          .get(endpoint)
          .then((res) => {
            setData((prev) => ({...prev, [endpoint]: res.data}));
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            setError((prev) => ({...prev, [endpoint]: err.message}));
          });
      })
    );
    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let timer: number | null = null;
    const intervalFetch = async () => {
      await fetching();
      timer = setTimeout(async () => {
        setError({});
        setData({});
        intervalFetch();
      }, 15000);
    };

    intervalFetch();

    return () => timer !== null && clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);

  if (loading) return <Spinner />;
  return (
    <div className="card-container">
      {Object.values(data).length ? (
        Object.values(data).map((item) => {
          return (
            <Card
              key={generateKey()}
              hostname={item.hostname}
              message={item.message}
              success={item.success}
              time={item.time}
            />
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <Spinner />
      )}
      {Object.values(error).length
        ? Object.values(error).map((err) => (
            <ErrorCard key={generateKey()} message={err as string} />
          ))
        : null}
    </div>)
```

Comment: Yes. I can see your point. it's in fact intentional. I have to render a card for each api response. and there are 18 endpoints. what happens with the useEffect without the cleanup function is that for some reason it renders 22 cards instead of 18. idk why

Comment: @AgustinGarcia It could well be that 1 ore more of those 18 requests takes a long time to come back. If one launched comes back in say, 20 seconds, then it will be appended to the wrong batch. If thats the case, the above will fix it since it waits for all of them to finish before launching the next 15 second timer for the next loop.

Comment: Ok I see it. I don’t really know about the response time but Ive tried the code shown above but for some reason it renders 22 cards instead of 22 each time. But I think it solve some issues because they doesn’t append to the other batch. I would need to solve the fact of rendering 22

Comment: I see. Can you (a) check the network requests in the network pane of the dev tools shows 18 requests per back and (b) show us the rest of the code that does the card rendering?

Comment: ok I've just updated my code. and i've checked and some endpoints are fetching more than once with the code you shared above and that JSX

Comment: Interesting...hmmm. Im not sure how thats happening. Is the `length` of endpoints definitely 18?

Comment: Yes. I'm gonna update my code again with my urls. maybe It's because I'm using a proxy in my package.json?

Comment: Are you using StrictMode by any chance?

Comment: I have edited my answer with a revised attempt that could work for you

Comment: Yes. I was using StrictMode. I've tried your new answer and it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this piece of code might be adding additional data instead of overwriting the existing one. Is that what you're trying to do?

```js
setData((prev) => [...prev, res.data]);
```